# How to write in Georgian on your iPhone?

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I'm looking to write using the Georgian language script Mkhedruli on my iPhone. I can't find Georgian Mkhedruli on the keyboard options anywhere. Just in case you don't know what Mkhedruli is, it's the script which looks like this:

მე და სჰენ. ქართველი ენა ლამაზი.

Do you know how I can write this on my phone?

Comment: Have you checked the App Store for keyboard apps that can do this?

Comment: Try using this app https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/georgian-keyboard/id900035450?mt=8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a search for "Georgian" in the App Store you will find any number of apps, both free and paid, for adding a Mkhreduli keyboard to your iPhone.

Only having a passing familiarity with the script I couldn't give you any expert recommendation. Try a couple of the free ones.